# How to track the event(Alarm event) in android

Tags: android, android-alarms

I want to develop an android application that do some stuff at the time any alarm rings in android. Actually, I want to track the event of alarm in android, and integrate my application   with alarm event and runs when alarm rings.

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported API for this, sorry.